# Accurate Seek in Pseudo-streaming Flash

Tags: html, flash, frame, mediaelement.js, seek

I would like to know if the flash fallback (medialement or any other) can support accurate seek to the frame for an H.264 video in a MP4 container, transferred by HTTP using an IIS or apache web server (HTTP Pseudostreaming or Progressive Download). In HTML5, we can order to seek to any frame number and it will manage to decode whatever is needed to display the requested frame index.

Currently, what I can experiment with all flash player is something like a seek to the closest GOP or keyframe. However, this is unfortunately not enough for my project as I really need to be able to reach any arbitrary frame.

Do you know if there is a way to have an frame accurate seek in Flash, using HTTP pseudo streaming (I know this is possible with FMS and RTMP streaming).

Comment: Thanks. Actually this is because we want to stream our MP4 files without any convertion. Most HTML5 browser provides this feature (seeking to an exact frame, frame by frame playback, even reverse frame by frame playback). But now the flash fallback of most players (jplayer, flowplayer,...). They all seek to the GOP or similar. I just would like to know if this is a limitation of the flash plugin itself or if this is feasible somehow. Thx